# Converting a pipe delimited CSV file to a JSON file in a certain format

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, list, csv

I am trying to convert from a CSV file each row into JSON format.

When I convert it to JSON it includes the square brackets at the beginning and the end, how can it be omitted?. Also I am looking for a way to split piped values into a list of separate hobbies.

This is what I am getting as output:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": "23",
    "Hobby": "Kayaking|Football",
    "Location": "Miami",
    "Profession": "Sales",
  },
  {
    "Name": "Peter",
    "Age": "35",
    "Hobby": "Football|Basketball|Swimming",
    "Location": "Turin",
    "Profession": "Mechanic",
  },
  {
    "Name": "James",
    "Age": "50",
    "Hobby": "Golf",
    "Location": "Berlin",
    "Profession": "Accountant",
  }
]
```

My desired output

```
  {
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": "23",
    "Hobby": ["Kayaking","Football"],
    "Location": "Miami",
    "Profession": "Sales",
  },
  {
    "Name": "Peter",
    "Age": "35",
    "Hobby": ["Football","Basketball","Swimming"],
    "Location": "Turin",
    "Profession": "Mechanic",
  },
  {
    "Name": "James",
    "Age": "50",
    "Hobby": "Golf",
    "Location": "Berlin",
    "Profession": "Accountant",
  }
```

My code:

```
import glob
import os
import csv
import json


if __name__ == '__main__':
    csv.register_dialect('piper', delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for filename in glob.glob('path_to_csv\file.csv'):
        csvfile = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        jsonfile = 'jsfile.json'
        fieldnames = ("Name","Age","Hobby","Location", "Profession")
    with open(csvfile+'.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f,fieldnames)#, dialect='piper')
        rows = list(reader)


    with open(jsonfile, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(rows, f, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': '))
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: You have a list of items, which is represented in JSON by separating those items with commas and surrounding the collection with brackets. It makes no sense to ask for a JSON representation of a list without the brackets – that's a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 0):

`rows = list(reader)`

There is no need to wrap it into the list since it is already a list. Removing this line will fix the brackets.

```
for row in reader:
   row['Hobby'] = list(row['Hobby'].split('|'))
```

We need to split the string of hobbies and convert them to list